# why Android listView onitemclicklistner update more than one item in the list?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

i use view holder to hold views in list view, and her my code

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 ViewHolder holder;

public MyAdapter(Context context/*,List<Music> list*//*,ListView listView*/){
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 15;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int p = 0;
    View view = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        holder= new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item, null);   
        holder.set = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.set);
        holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new lis(position,holder));

    return convertView;
}
class lis implements OnClickListener{
    private int p;
    private ViewHolder holder;



    public lis(int p,ViewHolder holder){
    this.p = p;
    this.holder = holder;

}
int counter=0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        p++;
        counter++;
        Log.e("counter ",String.valueOf(counter));
        holder.set.setText("" + counter);
    }

}
  static class ViewHolder{
    Button button = null;
    TextView set = null;
}
```

}

but when i click on an item in the list for example i click on item 1 to increase its value by +1, but in this code it also increase other two items with +1 as will, where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the fact, that you're data is stored in the click listener. *It shouldn't.*

The `ListView` component doesn't generate view for each item in the list. So, there won't be `15` of them in your case. There will be just as many as can fit on the screen. When you scroll the list, the old items, which are no longer visible, *are recycled*. The `getView` is then called with `convertView != null` and the adapter is giving you an opportunity to *update* this recycled item view. Since you don't update the view, and only assign a new click listener, the item *seems* to have a `count` of `1`, but it's just the old item view being recycled.

Moreover, updating recycled view won't help in your case, since item data is declared in your click listener. Move it outside, for example in the adapter:

```
private int[] counters = new int[15];
```

Then, in the click listener, access count of the item in question by its position:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    counters[p]++;
    int count = counters[p];
    holder.set.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Finally, in `getView()`, always update item view to reflect current count:

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new lis(position,holder));
holder.set.setText(String.valueOf(counters[position]));
```

Comment: glad to hear that :) consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. take care!